# Reset <md-checkbox> for Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular material 2 library and `md-checkbox` element.

Something like:

```html
<md-checkbox id="myInput"
             labelPosition="after"
             (change)="toggleOnChange($event)">
  Label
</md-checkbox>
```

Later on some other event (not related to this input) I want to reset its state (mark unchecked if checked). How do I do it? Does the API support it? [According to the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api), there is no method for doing so.

If I try toggling classes on the element, that 'visually' unchecks it, but the state is kept.

Comment: can you be more specific , you want the inner model to reflect the change or the label even

Comment: what i am guessing is you want true if checked , else false right ?

Comment: I'm not using any model for it, so I thought I could do it without it. I just need to 'unmark' it on other event (.e.g I press reset button).

Comment: ohh so if it checked , you can uncheck by a different button something like that ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your checkbox some name e.g. `myCheckBox` and set the property `myCheckBox.checked` to `false` on button click.

```
<md-checkbox id="myInput" labelPosition="after" 
    #myCheckBox (change)="toggleOnChange($event)">Label
</md-checkbox>
<button md-button (click)="myCheckBox.checked = false">Reset Checkbox</button>

OR Like this:

<button md-button (click)="someFunction(myCheckBox)">Reset Checkbox In Method</button>
```

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-sftcrb?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I missed naming elements via `#myCheckBox`

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is best done by using an NgControl (like NgModel or FormControl). The checkbox does have a `toggle()` method. If you know whether the checkbox is already checked or not, you can toggle it accordingly

> **toggle** | Toggles the checked state of the checkbox

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

Comment: Okay, so in that case, how do I check if it's 'checked'? In that case I would trigger 'toggle'.

Comment: See @Faisal's answer. It is more straightforward.